# Excel GetPivotData - Use a Variable for Copying Down

Tags: excel, pivot-table

When referencing a Column in a PivotTable using GetPivotData how do you make it be suitable to copy down and not hold onto the column value as fixed which usually in my case is a persons name.

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("AHT",$A$4,"Operator","Samara Callum","WeekEnding",DATE(2016,4,10))
```

So Currently when copying down I received the same result of **B6** copied down however I need It to follow **B7** **B8** etc.

In the above example Samara Callum is the value that needs to change its reference moving down.

How do I achieve this?

**Edit** This post from Mr.Excel shows how to disable GitPivotData and create a fixed reference but not a full solution to obtaining the question http://mrexcel.com/getpivotdata.html

Comment: try using a reference to samara callum as your criteria instead of the actual value.  for example, if samara callum is in cell d1, and the next name you need is in d2, and so on, you would put d1 in the criteria in place of samara then when you copy the formula down to other cells they will update to d2, d3, etc  i think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Tried that and it created a #ref error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a reference like this

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("AHT",$A$4,"Operator",**B6**,"WeekEnding",DATE(2016,4,10))
```

or following the format on myonlinetraninghub us a row.

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("AHT",$A$4,"Operator",**ROW(B6)**,"****WeekEnding",DATE(2016,4,10))
```

Guide solution found on at [myonlinetraininghub](http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-getpivotdata-function)